# API Request in Dialogflow Fulfillment (Javascript)

Tags: api, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

So I'm trying to make a google action using Dialogflow that requires an external API. I've always used jQuery `.getJSON()` to make API calls, so I had no idea how to do this. After searching this up online, I found a way to do this using vanilla javascript (I also tested the way on my website and it worked fine). The code for that is below:

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
  };

  xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?lang=en-es&key=trnsl.1.1.20190105T052356Z.7f8f950adbfaa46e.9bb53211cb35a84da9ce6ef4b30649c6119514a4&text=eat", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

The code worked fine on my website, but as soon as I added it to the Dialogflow, it would give me the error

> XMLHttpRequest is not defined

Obviously that happened because I never defined it (using `var`), except it worked without me doing anything. So then, I tried adding this line

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
```

to the code, and it stopped giving me the error (because I defined XMLHttpRequest). But then, my code wouldn't work.

**TL;DR:** How can I make an external API call using Dialogflow fulfillment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `https`. But make sure that you upgrade to Blaze Pay(or any other plans) to make external API calls, else you will receive an error such as

```
Error:
Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions.
```

Code to make external api call,

```
// See https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs
// for Dialogflow fulfillment library docs, samples, and to report issues
"use strict";

const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const { WebhookClient } = require("dialogflow-fulfillment");
const { Card, Suggestion } = require("dialogflow-fulfillment");
const https = require("https");

process.env.DEBUG = "dialogflow:debug"; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(
  (request, response) => {
    const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
    console.log(
      "Dialogflow Request headers: " + JSON.stringify(request.headers)
    );
    console.log("Dialogflow Request body: " + JSON.stringify(request.body));

    function getWeather() {
      return weatherAPI()
        .then(chat => {
          agent.add(chat);
        })
        .catch(() => {
          agent.add(`I'm sorry.`);
        });
    }

    function weatherAPI() {
      const url =
        "https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22";

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        https.get(url, function(resp) {
          var json = "";
          resp.on("data", function(chunk) {
            console.log("received JSON response: " + chunk);
            json += chunk;
          });

          resp.on("end", function() {
            let jsonData = JSON.parse(json);
            let chat = "The weather is " + jsonData.weather[0].description;
            resolve(chat);
          });
        });
      });
    }

    function welcome(agent) {
      agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
    }

    function fallback(agent) {
      agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
      agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
    }

    let intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set("Default Welcome Intent", welcome);
    intentMap.set("Default Fallback Intent", fallback);
    intentMap.set("Weather Intent", getWeather);
    agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
  }
);
```

Comment: What is Blaze Pay and how much does it cost?

Comment: Don't have much idea on these. You can use the mention link to get more info.
https://firebase.google.com/pricing/?authuser=0

Answer (score 0):

This article is a diamond! It really helped to clarify what's going on and what's required in Dialogflow fullfilments.

A small suggestion is to gracefully catch the error in the connection to the webservice:

```
      function weatherAPI() {
        const url = "https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22";

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            https.get(url, function(resp) {
                var json = "";
                resp.on("data", function(chunk) {
                    console.log("received JSON response: " + chunk);
                    json += chunk;
                });

                resp.on("end", function() {
                    let jsonData = JSON.parse(json);
                    let chat = "The weather is " + jsonData.weather[0].description;
                    resolve(chat);
                });

            }).on("error", (err) => {
                reject("Error: " + err.message);
            });

        });
      }
```